# How to get last purchase date when reaching certain sum value with criteria (Query or Gsheet)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having some trouble to last purchase date when reaching certain sum value with criteria.

**More context:**

I have two source from sample data:

[image: Inventory Data]

This is the inventory data for each product with specified qty per inbound number (inbound 1 was the earliest inbound) and date

[image: Transaction Data]

This is the transaction data for each product based on date

**Problem:**
I want to extract the last purchase date with criteria of when the inbound 1 reached zero, the formula automatically moved to next inbound qty , so ideally I would to get this results:

[image: Last Purchase Date]

The quantities on the transaction will be based on the inbound, for example, transaction #1 will use qty on the Inbound 1.
Transaction #2 will use the qty on the next inbound which is inbound 2, since the qty on inbound 1 already reached zero because it has been used on transaction #1

Also, this is the sample sheet that can be the reference: [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d7TZqqKCn3AO60BLtNDoRjVB7MQ-yhelPAIretVVHLA/edit#gid=920669902)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `when the inbound 1 reached zero`, how you are defining that it reaches zero?

Comment: Hmm, I think it would be more simple if I explained this:
the quantities on the transaction will be based on the inbound, for example, transaction #1 will use qty on the Inbound 1. 
transaction #2 will use the qty on the next inbound which is inbound 2, since the qty on inbound 1 already reached zero because it has been used on transaction #1

Comment: A transaction can use 2 consecutive Inbound quantities right? For example, if Inbound 1 runs out and 1 item of A is still required, that will be drawn from Inbound 2?

Comment: yes that's right, also technically the real data with reach to inbound 20 and more

Comment: Another issue is your definition of "last purchase". In your current example, Inbound 2 Item B has not been exhausted. So you just want the last purchase of item B in that case instead of leaving it empty? Empty would be the consistent answer for your requirement of "last purchase that exhausts an Inbound quantity"

Comment: Hmm yes, if that’s the case than the last puchase has to be generated eventhough the qty on the inbound 2 still not exhausted

Comment: Ok. I'll have an answer for you.

Comment: @sqysan: Just so you know, my initial answer had an error (copy pasted wrong things) and the edited answer is the intended answer. When in doubt, the formula in your example sheet is correct and you can always vary the test examples there to verify

Comment: @Argyll: Just curious, does this formula still works if my source for inbound qty and transactions are from different tab? instead of being on the same sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
=bycol(vstack(B3:E3,scan(vstack(0,0,0),B3:E3,lambda(aa,cc,
       reduce(vstack(cc+index(aa,1,1),index(aa,2,1),index(aa,3,1)),$J$3:$J,
             lambda(a,c,if(row(c)<=index(aa,2,1),
                           a,
                           if(offset(c,0,-1)=A3,
                              if(index(a,1,1)<=0,
                                 a,
                                 if(c>=index(a,1,1),
                                    vstack(index(a,1,1)-c,row(c),offset(c,0,-2)),
                                    vstack(index(a,1,1)-c,row(c),offset(c,0,-2)))),
                              a))))))),
    lambda(col,if(index(col,2,1)>=index(col,1,1),tocol(,1),index(col,4,1))))
```

for product A and drag down to as many product as you need.

Alternatively, if you wish to centralize the formula in order to accommodate a dynamic product list, you can add another layer of `byrow` as follows.

```js
=byrow(B3:E4,lambda(rw,bycol(vstack(rw,scan(vstack(0,0,0),rw,lambda(aa,cc,
      reduce(vstack(cc+index(aa,1,1),index(aa,2,1),index(aa,3,1)),$J$3:$J,
             lambda(a,c,if(row(c)<=index(aa,2,1),
                           a,
                           if(offset(c,0,-1)=offset(index(rw,1,1),0,-1),
                              if(index(a,1,1)<=0,
                                 a,
                                 if(c>=index(a,1,1),
                                    vstack(index(a,1,1)-c,row(c),offset(c,0,-2)),
                                    vstack(index(a,1,1)-c,row(c),offset(c,0,-2)))),
                              a))))))),lambda(cl,if(index(cl,2,1)>=index(cl,1,1),tocol(,1),index(cl,4,1))))))
```

Implicit in your requirements are:

- if an inbound inventory is not exhausted at the end of the transaction, then the last date a transaction uses its inventory should be posted
- if an inbound inventory is never used, no date should be posted

In order to demonstrate fulfillment of the above requirements, I extended your example to have Inbound 3 and Inbound 4 and increased the transaction quantities. You can see for Product B, where Inbound 3 has been used but not exhausted and therefore the last date of its use is posted; and Inbound 4 is never used and therefore no date is posted.

Do be careful with aggregating a lot of calculations in one formula. I am not sure if there is a hard limit by Google Sheet on how much computing time one formula can cost.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, i’ll try to use it on my real data

Comment: Just curious, does this formula still works if my source for inbound qty and transactions are from different tab? instead of being on the same sheet

Comment: Yes, you just need to fill in the correct ranges. Note that 3 ranges are used: the data cells for Inbound quantities `B3:E3`; the name of the product `A3`; the transaction columns `$J$3:$J`. Although only Qty column is directly referenced, implicitly, Product names are always expected to be on the left of its column (ie. Column I in this case) and Date always to another left (ie. Column H in this case). This last part is encoded in `offset` usage. When you copy paste, double check all 3 ranges make sense

Comment: Thanks for your help, also if you don't mind, i have a follow-up question. Is it possible to combine this formula with arrayformula? since i have 5000+ products, it would be heavy on the sheets to load those formula on each product cell

Comment: @sqysan: Use [`map`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en). `arrayformula` is unlikely to work when multiple ranges are referenced in a complex manner. Use techniques like `if(isblank(...` to allow for ranges without no rows.

Comment: I tried to use **MAP** but it keeps having an error, could you suggest the formula if we have to use **MAP** for 2000 products row? thank you

Comment: @sqysan: By the way, the formula is heavy not because of dragging (which you can do with double-clicking), but because the whole list of transactions is scanned with intermediate values being created and stored for *every* inbound number. If this was a custom script, you would cut the scan when an inbound quantity is exhausted -- basically iterating through both inbound list and transaction list simultaneously and each only once. There is no array function in Google Sheet that supports recursion or stop conditions that I know of. So the inefficiency is something you'd have to accept.

Comment: @sqysan: I can edit it into the answer

Comment: @sqysan: I added a 2nd formula with `byrow` that centralizes the formulas in the answer and in your example sheet. But be careful with centralizing too much calculation into one formula. Google Sheet may hard cap computing time spent on 1 formula (to catch infinite loop situations).

Comment: I see, alright then. I'll try to tweak the formula again with your guidance above.
Thank you once again Argyll

Comment: @sqysan: Np. My last tip would be to note where `offset` is used. Instead of offsetting by 1 column, you can for example make it `offset(c,0,column(c)-column($I$3:$I))`. That way, if you insert a column between column I (Qty) and column J (Product) in your transaction columns, Google Sheet will automatically update the range `$I$3:$I`. (That's column K and L of your present example sheet, assuming it hasnt changed by the time you see this comment.) And that applies to all `offset` usage. As a result, you are not required to keep the formatting of your example sheet for eternity.

Comment: @sqysan: The trade-off is code readability.

Answer (score 0):

For Inbound#1

```
=INDEX(G:G, XMATCH(A14,H:H,0,-1)-1)
```

For Inbound#2

```
=INDEX(G:G, XMATCH(A14,H:H,0,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harun, i would like to ask
Since technically my data will reach inbound 20 and beyond, what needs to be changed on the formula?

Comment: @sqysan I think just drag down the formula should work and adjust column references for your actual case.

Comment: Doesnt `xmatch` simply extracts the last purchase? I think OP's requirement is that the inbound inventory is exhausted one after another. For example, had `B4` been 1 in the example, then the correct answer for Inbound 1, item B would be `G3`. But the `xmatch` output would not change and would still be `G4`.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like xmatch didnt generate the result that I require, I have tried using offset, but not successful so far